# I'm stuck on this Error from Udemy course on NodeJS and express by Jonas Schmidtmann

Tags: node.js, react-helmet

I have tried multiple solutions on here, but nothing seems to work, can anybody help me ??

GET https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.1/mapbox-gl.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 200

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of this error, try install cors as a dependency. Now if you're using express try this code

```
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}));
```